# C# Custom Json.NET List serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a List of DataObject classes:

```
public class DataObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }
}



public class Field
{

    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }

    public Field(string name, string type, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        if(type == "string") Value = (string)value;
        else Value = Int32.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

and i would like to serialize List made of DataObject classes to .json file.  the way I show below using Json.NET, I have tried few scenarios but didn't find out how to do this.

Example:

```
Field field1 = new Field("Brand", "string", "Volvo);
Field field2 = new Field("Power", "int", 200);
List<Field> fields = new List<Field>{field1, field2};
DataObject car = new DataObject{
   Name = "Car",
   Fields = list
}
List<DataObjects> objects = new List<DataObjects>{car};
```

Result:

```
{
 "Car":{
   "Brand" : "Volvo",
   "Power" : 200
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the JSON supposed to look like if there are multiple `DataObjects` in the list?

Answer (score 3):

Using Newtonsoft.Json, Serialization is rather easy. I took your code and added the following line:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

and it gave me the following output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Car",
    "Fields": [
      {
        "Name": "Brand",
        "Type": "string",
        "Value": "Volvo"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Power",
        "Type": "int",
        "Value": 200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I get it, but how to make variable Name (in my case for example "Brand"), a tag for variable Value (for example "Volvo") to get `"Brand" : "Volvo"` etc.